# Python PySide QDateEdit

Tags: python, pyside

I have a `QDateEdit` object (field on a display window). When I use the only real option (according to the PySide site) `QDateEdit.date()` I get "2000, 1, 1" instead of "1/1/2000" and the documentation is completely useless for telling what to do with this data to use it as a real date. "2000, 1, 1" isn't a real date.

How to make this a date I can actually use and why I can't use any of the attributes described on the PySide site under `QDate`, `QDateEdit`, or `QDateTimeEdit`?

Comment: Why isn't "2000, 1, 1" a real date? Looks like January 1st, 2000 to me...

Comment: [`QDateEdit.date().toString("dd/MM/yyyy")`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QDate.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QDate.toString) might help. But before that like Mark asked why isn't it real date?

Answer (score 1):

I am having a hard time trying to determine what you mean by "real date", but here is my idea of what you could want:

```
# QDateEdit's .date() returns a QtCore.QDate object
date = QtCore.QDate(2013, 1, 1)

# Get the string in whatever format you want
date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
Out[10]: u'01/01/2013'

# Get the date as a datetime object
date.toPython()
Out[11]: datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)
```

I got all of this from the [PySide wiki](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QDate.html#PySide.QtCore.QDate)